# Can this equation have four integer solutions?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find three numbers `a, b, c` so that the equation
$(x+a)^4 + (x+b)^4 = c$ have four integer solutions.
I tried

```
f[x_] := (x + a)^4 + (x + b)^4 - c
Eliminate[{f[x] == 0 // PowerExpand, x + (a + b)/2 == t}, x] // FullSimplify
```

> (a - b)^4 + 24 (a - b)^2 t^2 + 16 t^4 == 8 c

And then, I solve

```
Solve[(a - b)^4 + 24 (a - b)^2 t^2 + 16 t^4 - 8 c == 0, t] // FullSimplify
```

> {{t -> -(1/2) Sqrt[-3 (a - b)^2 -
> 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(a - b)^4 + c]]}, {t ->
> 1/2 Sqrt[-3 (a - b)^2 - 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(a - b)^4 + c]]}, {t -> -(1/
> 2) Sqrt[-3 (a - b)^2 + 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(a - b)^4 + c]]}, {t ->
> 1/2 Sqrt[-3 (a - b)^2 + 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(a - b)^4 + c]]}}

Now I put

```
r1 = -(1/2) Sqrt[-3 (a - b)^2 - 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(a - b)^4 + c]] - (a + b)/2;
r2 = 1/2 Sqrt[-3 (a - b)^2 - 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(a - b)^4 + c]] - (a + b)/
   2;
r3 = -(1/2) Sqrt[-3 (a - b)^2 + 
    2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(a - b)^4 + c]] - (a + b)/2;
r4 = 1/2 Sqrt[-3 (a - b)^2 + 2 Sqrt[2] Sqrt[(a - b)^4 + c]] - (a + b)/
   2;
```

Comment: This sequence is of relevance https://oeis.org/A003824

Comment: Do $a$, $b$, and $c$ have to be real?  Positive?  Integers?  All of the above?

Comment: Also note that the first two of your solutions for $t$ are pretty obviously going to be complex numbers if $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real.  If that's the case there's no way that you're going to get four distinct integer solutions.

Comment: Another way to see this is that if you define $f(x) = (x+a)^4 + (x+b)^4 - c$, then $f''(x) = 12(x+a)^2 + 12(x+b)^2 \geq 0$.  This means that the graph is concave up everywhere, and so $f(x)$ cannot have more than two real roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation has a maximum of two *real* solutions, so having four integer solutions is out of the question:

```
Solve[f[x]==0, x, Reals]  

{{x -> ConditionalExpression[
         Root[ (* original polynomial *), 1], 
         a^4 - 4 a^3 b + 6 a^2 b^2 - 4 a b^3 + b^4 - 8 c < 0]},
 {x -> ConditionalExpression[
         Root[ (* original polynomial *), 2], 
         a^4 - 4 a^3 b + 6 a^2 b^2 - 4 a b^3 + b^4 - 8 c < 0]}}
```

In other words, there are two real roots if $(a-b)^4 - 8 c < 0$, and no real roots otherwise.

To see why this is using high-school algebra techniques, apply the transformation $x = \sqrt{u}-\frac12(a+b)$:

```
FullSimplify[Expand[f[x] /. {x -> Sqrt[u] - (a + b)/2}]]

(* 1/8 (a - b)^4 - c + 3 (a - b)^2 u + 2 u^2 *)
```

Each of the two roots $u_\pm$ of this polynomial will correspond to two roots of the original polynomial.  If we want real roots for $x$, then both the roots for $u$ must be real and positive.
But the sum of the roots of this latter polynomial is $-3(a-b)^2/2 < 0$.  So at least one solution for $u$ must be negative, meaning that there is at most one positive root for $u$ and therefore at most two real roots for $x$.

We can ensure that the other $u$ root is positive by noting that the product of the roots of the quadratic polynomial is $(\frac18(a - b)^4 - c)/2$.  Since one root is negative, and we want the other root to be positive, this quantity must be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
solx = Values@Solve[(x + a)^4 + (x + b)^4 - c == 0, x] // Flatten
cond=Reduce[Element[solx,Integers],{a,b,c},Reals]
```

[image]

Forcing the last two conditions we find

```
cond /. c -> -a^4 + 4 a^3 b - 6 a^2 b^2 + 4 a b^3 - b^4 /. b -> a
(*(a | a | a | a) \[Element] Integers*)
```

solution `a=b=integer,c=0`

Comment: I would interpret the original question as seeking 4 different integer roots, not a single root repeated 4 times (which I think you have).

Comment: Agrred, but result of my evaluation gives 4 identical roots.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve $(x+a)^4 + (x+b)^4 = c$ for integer values. The result is a `ConditionalExpression` with one integer constant.

```
Clear[a,b,c,x]
sol = First[Solve[(x+a)^4 + (x+b)^4 == c, x, Integers]];
```

> ```
> {x -> ConditionalExpression[C[1],
>   Element[a, Integers] && Element[b, Integers] &&
>   Element[C[1], Integers] &&
>   c == a^4 + b^4 + 4*a^3*C[1] + 4*b^3*C[1] + 6*a^2*C[1]^2 +
>   6*b^2*C[1]^2 + 4*a*C[1]^3 + 4*b*C[1]^3 + 2*C[1]^4]}
> ```

Let's use `sol` to find values for `x`, `a`, `b`, and `c`.

```
TableForm[With[{xx = 1}, (* x, a, and b are any integers *)
  Flatten[Table[{xx, i, j, (x/.sol/.{a->i, b->j, C[1]->xx})[[2,2]]},
    {i, -2, 2}, {j, -2, 2}], 1]],
TableHeadings->{None,{"x","a","b","c"}}]
```

| x | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -2 | -2 | 2 |
| 1 | -2 | -1 | 1 |
| 1 | -2 | 0 | 2 |
|  | ... |  |  |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 82 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 97 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | 162 |

Another way to see the results is to compute `c` from values of `a` and `b` and plot the result.

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten[
  Table[{i, j, (x/.sol/.{a->i, b->j, C[1]->1})[[2,2]]},
    {i, -10, 10}, {j, -10, 10}], 1],
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {a,b}, BaseStyle -> {Bold, 14}]
```

[image: 3D plot]

We can make a list of random solutions.

```
SeedRandom[1357];
numSamples = 5;
TableForm[
Sort@Flatten[Last[Reap[Do[
  Sow[{xx, a, b, Last[(x/.sol)/.C[1]->xx/.Equal->List][[-1, -1]]}/.
    {a->#1, b->#2, xx->#3}&@@RandomInteger[{-9, 9}, 3]],numSamples]]], 1],
TableHeadings->{None,{"x", "a", "b", "c"}}]
```

| x | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -9 | 9 | -3 | 20736 |
| -7 | -4 | -1 | 18737 |
| -2 | -1 | 5 | 162 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 881 |
| 9 | -5 | 0 | 6817 |

Check that `x`, `a`, `b`, and `c` are a valid solution.

```
checkTrueQ[{x_, a_, b_, c_}] := (x + a)^4 + (x + b)^4==c
checkTrueQ[{-9, 9, -3, 20736}]
(*True*)
```

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly you've found a way to generate values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ so that the equations $(x+a)^4 + (x+b)^4 = c$ has *one* integer solution.  But the OP wanted this equation to have four (presumably distinct) integer solutions.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, that's what I've done. That's how I understand John's question. I see that your answer says there can't be four simultaneous solutions. Maybe John will explain his goal.